# Using Pandas in CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python, kindly help me to understand and go forward in python learning. Find below the sample data:

```
Country Age Sal OnWork
USA 52 12345 No
UK 23 1142 Yes
MAL 25 4456 No
```

I would like to find the mean value in SAL column if OnWork is NO

Comment: `County Age Salary OnWork
USA 52 11456 No
UK 25 1235 Yes
Singapore 45 4456 No`

Not sure how to update Table format here.....

Comment: please explain your question .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's Say that your data looks like the following,

```
{'Country': 'USA', 'Age': '52', 'Sal': '12345', 'OnWork': 'No'}
{'Country': 'UK', 'Age': '23', 'Sal': '1142', 'OnWork': 'Yes'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '25', 'Sal': '4456', 'OnWork': 'No'}
```

The below code will be of help in your case:

```
df = your_dataframe
df[df["OnWork"]=="No"]["Sal"].mean()
```

Comment: Whether I can use IF of Where class to find YES and NO values mean.

Comment: You can use df.filter(items = ["OnWork","Sal"],axis=1).groupby(by = ["OnWork"]).mean()

Comment: I am getting IndentationError: unexpected indent error. The real spreadsheet has more than 10k lines in 7coloums

Comment: please check your code indentation, if problem still persists please post the complete traceback by editing the question.